# How events actually works as a parameters in python? What should i put as a function parameter when call out?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a mouse_press_event function in Logic class with event parameter for reading mouse position with each click.

```
 def mouse_press_event(self, event):
    try:
        pixmap = Logic.get_pixmap(self)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.drawButton.isChecked() and pixmap:
            self.coordinates.append({
                'x': event.pos().x(),
                'y': event.pos().y()
            })
```

I'd like to call out this function with mousePressEvent in Qlabel, in my UI class but i have to give it 2 parameters

```
self.imageLabel.mousePressEvent = Logic.mouse_press_event(self, required_event)
```

What should i put in 'required_event' and why?

Comment: I'm wondering if you're misunderstanding event handling. Usually, you don't call the handler function yourself - rather, you bind the function to the event so that Qt can call it when the event occurs. The Qt tutorials should show you how to do that.

Comment: Event handlers are functions that the object you inherit already calls when certain things occur. **You don't call them**.